# How to set HTTP response (cache) headers in a Sinatra app hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby, caching, http-headers, heroku, sinatra

I have a fairly simple app (just one `index.html` file and a css file - it really is just a static page) hosted on Heroku.

I use Sinatra to host it on Heroku. The 'app' itself is fairly simple:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get "/" do
    File.read(File.join('public', 'index.html'))
end
```

The question is, how do I set the HTTP response header for the static assets? In particular, I wanted to set the `Expires` header for caching purposes.

EDIT: I'm looking to add the said header to the static assets (ie, the one that resides under `/public`, like background images, icons, etc)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apart from the fact that I wouldn't get through the Sinatra stack just to serve static files, you'd call

```
cache_control :public, max_age: 60
```

to cache for a minute. `cache_control` is a [helper that comes with Sinatra](http://railsapi.com/doc/sinatra-v1.0/classes/Sinatra/Helpers.html).

Otherwise, I'd suggest you have a look at http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html to see how Sinatra is set up so you don't have do deal with serving static files.

Hope this helps.

edit: I just saw you were explicitly asking for the `Expires` header. I'm not sure, but that should be fairly the same way as `Cache-Control`. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: How would you do it then? Assuming I still want it to be hosted on Heroku.

Comment: Note that Heroku suggests `Cache-Control` in their docs (see http://docs.heroku.com/http-caching), and Headhunter is hosted there. I'd use `response['Expires'] = `. Note that `Expires` is specified as absolute time, not relative to the request (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21)

Comment: Sinatra actually has a helper specifically for this: `cache_control :public, :max_age => 60`

Comment: @bjeanes Thanks, I've updated the answer. This has been around since at least 1.0 :)

Answer (score 6):

As an expansion to @awendt's answer, Sinatra can actually handle static files with out needing to explicitly define the route and print the file.

By adding:

```
set :static, true
```

..you can add your `index.html` and `stylesheet.css` to a `public/` folder.  Then when you visit `http://localhost:9292/stylesheet.css` you'll be provided with the static file.

If you want to use another folder name, instead of the default `public/`, then try:

```
set :public, "your_folder_name"
```

If we want to be less explicit we can just create the `public/` folder in the knowledge that Sinatra will enable `:static` for us anyway :)

**Source:** http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__enabledisable_static_file_routes